# How does Hyperledger Fabric handles the transaction execution when multiple clients want to update the same asset?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Since Hyperledger Fabric has a workaround to avoid double spending by checking the read set versioning with the world state versioning.
Assuming there is a client that issues transaction to update the same asset then the coming transactions by my knowledge will be invalidated by the peers.
To my understanding this means in one block there should only be one transaction for one asset update and note more.

Any help, could you please confirm my assumptions.

Highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric uses `Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC)` is used to address double-spending problems.

Fabric’s underlying databases use MVCC to make sure no double-spending or inconsistency in data will occur. In understandable terms, this means it’s using versioned documents or records (Since it’s a key-value store, we call each row a document or record). When updating the same state, a new version of an existing document will be made to overwrite the old one. Any transaction executed between this time will not be cleared and an MVCC error will be triggered. The advantage of using versioning overlocking like other databases is that even under high load, the DB can run at full speed asynchronously. This is why in modern databases MVCC is more widely used.